# In x8086 Assembly Language, how do I check if a char is an uppercase letter?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, uppercase

I am currently writing a program that takes in a password and checks for strength based on certain criteria, I am having trouble determining if my logic is correct for checking for an uppercase letter.

```
    mov cx, count
    mov bx, OFFSET pw

    upper_loop:

        mov ax, [bx]
        cmp dx, count
        je  upper_msg ; prompt user that no uppercase letter was entered
        sub ax, 'A'
        cmp ax, 'Z' - 'A'
        jle lower_check
        inc bx
        inc dx

        jmp upper_loop
```

Comment: Yes, looks correct except for the fact that you process 16 bits not 8. I don't think you deal with unicode here? So change `ax` to `al` everywhere.

Comment: Which character set and encoding? ('A' - 'Z' are unlikely to be the only uppercase letters in the character set your program is taking input from. That's why there are libraries for `isupper()`.) (If you mean to consider only 'A'-'Z', give your users [as well as your code maintainers] a break and tell them so.)

Comment: Instead of x8086, it should be 8086 or x86, where the x is a wildcard so that x86 means 8086, 80186, 80286, 80386, 80486, 80586, 80686, and even 8088. These are also collectively known as IA-32 processors. [Now, X64 is a different thing entirely: a processor which includes x86 instructions on an eXtended 64-bit architecture. I imagine that's what you are transparently running your x86 program on.]

Answer (score 2):

Your program is not correct, it may give false positives when the password contains for instance '@' (0x40) instead of capital letter. Subtracting 'A' from '@' yields -1 (0xFF), which **is** lower than 'Z'-'A' (0x19), so you jump to lower_check although no uppercase letter has been actually encountered. My proposition is to avoid comparing characters as signed numbers:

```
  mov cx, count
  mov si, OFFSET pw
  cld
upper_loop:
  lodsb
  cmp al,'A'
  jb not_u
  cmp al,'Z'
  jbe lower_check ; Break if at least one uppercase letter is present.
not_u:loop upper_loop
upper_msg ; prompt user that no uppercase letter was entered
```

Answer (score 1):

- I don't see that you cleared DX before running the loop.
- You need to retrieve bytes from the string since you clearly raise its pointer by just 1 on each iteration.
- You must interpret the result of the comparison in an unsigned way or else all the ASCII's from 0 to 64 would be considered uppercase letters!

Sticking to your example, this is the result:

```
    xor dx, dx
    mov cx, count
    mov bx, OFFSET pw
upper_loop:
    mov al, [bx]
    cmp dx, count
    je  upper_msg ; prompt user that no uppercase letter was entered
    sub al, 'A'
    cmp al, 'Z' - 'A'
    jbe lower_check
    inc bx
    inc dx
    jmp upper_loop
```